# Executing decompression when reading table to DataTable

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a query to get a Name (string) and Value (byte[]) from a MySQL table. The query is all executing, because if I put a breakpoint on the final line, I can look at the data DataTable and see the records with the Name field populated. However, the Value field is null.

```
var queryString = "SELECT Name, DECOMPRESS(Value) FROM myTable";
var query = new MySqlQuery(myMySqlConnection, queryString);            
var data = new DataTable();
            
try         
{
    // Tried to execute first, no change
    // query.ExecuteNonQuery();

    var da = new MySqlDataAdapter(query);
    await da.FillAsync(data);
}
finally
{
    await connection.CloseAsync();
}

results = JArray.FromObject(data).ToObject<List<Record>>();
```

If I remove DECOMPRESS from the query, I get the expected data (just compressed which isn't useful to me).

I have also tried putting putting `data.Load(reader)` in a `while(reader.Read())` loop, but this throws an exception due to the Reader being closed.

Do I need to do something to get the uncompressed data into my DataTable?

Comment: `SELECT Name, DECOMPRESS(Value) AS Value...` maybe?

Comment: If it's that simple I'm going to be so angry :P I'll test and get back to you.

Comment: @Charlieface write an answer, points are all yours. A full workday I've spent on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give the column an alias:

```
SELECT Name, DECOMPRESS(Value) AS Value
FROM ...
```